# Why is it called the "Unscented" transform?

Tags: math-history, transformation

I have not been able to track down the reason the [Unscented Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unscented_transform) has the name it has. Can anyone shed some light on the meaning of the term "unscented" in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.ieeeghn.org/wiki/index.php/First-Hand%3aThe_Unscented_Transform): it was inspired by seeing unscented deodorant on a coworker's desk. Somewhat of a let-down, but at least I know now.

Comment: That site is also a good discussion of Kalman filtering and applications.